# Auto brightness turned off, but it's not

Tags: screen-brightness

I have problem with auto brightness setting on my android smartphone.
Auto brightness turned off in settings, however it still works via not changing the display brightness, but changing lighntess(or contrast, idk) of the intarface colors.

VIDEOS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVwxZ.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqFxj.jpg

SPECS:
Android 11
MIUI 12

Does anyone know a solution of this problem?
It's really important for my work with UI Design.